# How do I fix a cracked front door pillar in Renault Megane 3?

Tags: body, megane

As you can see in the images, there are at least 3 cracks on the front (A) pillar for the door of the Renault Megane 3. I wonder whether this section (where it is connected to the door check arm) is plastic because I cannot imagine how the metal would crack that way. But anyway, how do I repair that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Metal does crack like that if it is able to flex repeatedly in the same place.

The easiest way to check if it is steel is to see if a magnet sticks to it.  I don't now what a Megane 3 is constructed from, but steel is the most likely, followed by aluminium.  Plastic is highly unlikely.

Presumably this is the component that stops the door opening further than it should and is located on the A pillar of the body.

A panel area like this is usually made up of at least two pressed steel components to add strength and rigidity.

These are some reasons why the panel may be flexing -

- A bad design - this will likely happen in the same place on all
  vehicles.
- Internal corrosion weakening the parts that add strength.
- There is a strengthening plate missing behind that panel.
- There is a faulty weld that is allowing the panel to move a small
  amount.
- The door is regularly allowed to swing open, beyond what it is designed for.

The only way to fix this properly is to weld the crack and repair whatever is allowing the panel to flex.  If it is a bad design, then maybe some internal strengthening needs adding.

Is the door often allowed to open to its limit, so that this component has to absorb the kinetic energy of the door swinging open?

I could also imagine that if this component is not lubricated and is stiff to operate, the action of closing the door could put increased load on the A pillar which could cause repeated flexing of the panel.

As a bodge fix, you may be able unscrew that bolt and add a small plate of steel between the panel and the component to stop it flexing, but you would need to be careful that the door still closes properly.

Comment: I would imagine another two reasons. The first is, that the screw was not tightly screwed so there was an extra movement, or three were extra shocks via the arm because of the worn vinyl tube on the other side of the component. In fact, I was getting to replace the arm with the new one, because when closing you can hear clapping which is usually an indication of this problem. But about 2 months ago, I figured out that this part of a pillar was bending up and down when the door opened and closed.